# 'CyclesContextProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: typescript

'CyclesContextProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type '({ children }: CyclesContextProviderProps) => void' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type '({ children }: CyclesContextProviderProps) => void' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

'CyclesContextProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type '({ children }: CyclesContextProviderProps) => void' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type '({ children }: CyclesContextProviderProps) => void' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

My App.tsx:

```
    <CyclesContextProvider>
      <Router />
    </CyclesContextProvider>
```

My CyclesContext:

interface CyclesContextProviderProps {
children: ReactNode
}

export function CyclesContextProvider({
children
}: CyclesContextProviderProps) {

Comment: Based on the error message, you're not returning anything from `CyclesContextProvider`. Make sure to `return children`, or similar